# Samba view real folder like symlink?

Tags: 16.04, windows, samba, configuration

I have installed an Ubuntu 16.04 six month ago. Since the installation, a Samba share folder is configurated an work like a charm. 
But this morning I have been surprised to see that all access "on this share" has been refused.

I can access to the directory shared but not in subdirectory. 
No changement in configuration have been made.

Samba conf is :

```
[global]
available = yes
read only = no
browsable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
ntlm auth = no
lanman auth = no
client ntlmv2 auth = yes
follow symlinks = no 
#server multi channel support = yes

[workspace]
path = /home/workspace
force user = developer
force group = developers
valid users = developer
```

In `/home/workspace` there is a folder by developer.

```
/home
-> /workspace
   -> /mvedie
   -> /other_dev1
   -> /other_dev2
   -> ....
```

Each developer have lots of folders.

```
/mvedie
-> /my_folder
-> /my_other_folder 
-> ....
```

Each developer works on Windows 7 computer and use "developer" user to mount network drive on `/workspace/his_developer_name`.

But in log file, I can see :

```
[2017/03/24 10:44:34.697182,  2] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:1298(check_reduced_name) check_reduced_name: Bad access attempt: my_folder is a symlink to mvedie/my_folder
[2017/03/24 10:44:34.697202,  3] ../source3/smbd/open.c:1144(open_file) Error opening file mvedie/my_folder(NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED) (local_flags=0) (flags=0)
```

If I add this configuration in [workspace] conf :

```
follow symkinks = yes
```

Everything work great. But I don't want to enable them.

`my_folder` is a real folder and not a symlink.

How do I solve this?

**Update 1**: Solved partially (see [my answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/896364/37165))

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be a bug due to samba update : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1675698

Wait for correction...

I rollback my version from 4.3.11 to 4.3.8 waiting patch release.